# Polyhedral homology manifold, but not topological manifold.

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex given by a set of vertices $V(K)$ and a distinguished set $S(K)$ (the simplexes) of finite non-empty subsets of $V(K)$. Given a simplex $\sigma \in S(K)$, its link is the subcomplex $Lk(\sigma)$ of $K$ formed by simplexes $\tau \in S(K)$ such that $\tau \cap \sigma=\emptyset$ and $\tau \cup \sigma \in S(K)$.

A polyhedral homology $n$-manifold is (according to [Hausmann's book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-09354-3)) a simplicial complex $M$ such that for each simplex $\sigma \in S(M)$ of dimension $k$, its link $Lk(\sigma)$ is a simplicial complex of dimension $n-k-1$ which has the homology of the sphere $S^{n-k-1}$.

Hausmman comments that it can be proven that simplicial complexes whose geometric realization are topological $n$-manifolds are polyhedral homology $n$-manifolds. But I couldn't find a polyhedral homology manifold that is not a topological manifold. Can someone show me one of these? Can it be done in dimension 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in dimension $2$, but you can do it in dimension $4$. First, start with a triangulated homology $3$-sphere $S$, such as the Poincare homology sphere. Let $M=\Sigma S$. This is a homology manifold but is not a manifold. It is more or less constructed to have the property of a homology manifold. (The link of each cone point is $S$, whereas the links of the other points are suspensions of actual spheres, so are spheres.) Intriguingly, if you suspend twice you get an actual sphere. This is the the [Double Suspension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem) of Cannon and Edwards.